# Grouping and Row limit in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2012

I want to have row limitation(for example, display only 10 rows in every page) to my table in the report. I could limit the rows with Ceiling method where I could find refer. However, I have to group based on two criteria before using row limit. One is I want to group by category by category name, after that group by based on Region. And have my row limit after that. How could I achieve this? And I want to do all of these in report level. Kindly share any insight on that matter.

Thanks.

Comment: If I have one grouping and have total at the end (will have row limit per page), with dummy-blank rows to fill up the table every page. How could I achieve then?

Comment: Because I have just tried out for the above scenario and quite convinced that two grouping and having page-break after each segment is quite impossible: rows will be jumping as it has more than one grouping, I have played around with Grouping by two categories and Sorting for display. But the result is not what I want. Thus, I am thinking maybe having two grouping won't give me what I am looking for. Instead, I will just focus on having total rows and blank rows to fill up the table layout. Any insight or workaround on this, please.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want to do this at report level here is what i can think of:

You can try reducing the value in `Height` section in `Interacivesize` property of your report according to your needs,which is set to 11in by default and shows whatever records can fit in that much space :

[image]

**Note:** In case you have a `small database` and want to show all the values in 1 page itself setting the Height value to 0 will do the trick for you. Hope this helps.